# gdb - why p/d output unsigned decimal?

Tags: debugging, gdb, decimal, signed

Refer to [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html), format `d` will print as signed decimal:

[image]

But `p/d  0xffffffff` give me `4294967295`, i expect the value should be `-1` instead:

```
(gdb) p/x  -1
+p/x  -1
$1 = 0xffffffff
(gdb) p/d  0xffffffff
+p/d  0xffffffff
$2 = 4294967295
(gdb) p/u  0xffffffff
+p/u  0xffffffff
$3 = 4294967295
(gdb)
```

Why both p/d and p/u return `4294967295` ? How should i print to output signed decimal `-1` ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why both p/d and p/u return 4294967295

When you give GDB `0xFFFFFFFF` input, it treats it as `unsigned int`. You can see this with `whatis`:

```
(gdb) p -1
$1 = -1
(gdb) p/d $1
$2 = -1
(gdb) p/u $1
$3 = 4294967295
(gdb) p/x $1
$4 = 0xffffffff
(gdb) whatis $1
type = int

(gdb) p/d 0xFFFFFFFF
$5 = 4294967295
(gdb) whatis $5
type = unsigned int
```

Comment: So should i conclude that it is gdb bug ?

Comment: @林果皞 Yes: re-reading the documentation, it looks like a GDB bug.